# pgadmin postgresql - register new local server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to setup pgAdmin on a new macbook. I am in the process of setting up a local server but keep getting the error:

`Error connecting to the server: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist`

Here are my settings:

[image: pgadmin_settings]

And here are the contents of my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     abc1234                                trust
#host    replication     abc1234        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     abc1234        ::1/128                 trust
host all all localhost trust
host all all 192.168.1.0/24 trust
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install `postgres` using `postgres.app` ?

Comment: i installed it using homebrew

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /usr/local/var/postgres` ?

Comment: drwx------  30 abc1234  admin  1020 May 29 20:46 /usr/local/var/postgres @donkopotamus

Comment: Are you `abc1234`?  Try using that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is telling you that the `postgres` role, which is the usual "superuser" in a postgresql installation, does not exist.

In this case, it seems that the cluster has been installed using a local user as the superuser:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/var/postgres
drwx------ 30 abc1234 admin 1020 May 29 20:46 /usr/local/var/postgres
```

In which case we can probably login using:

```
$ psql -U abc1234 postgres
```

Comment: Gotcha - that works in the terminal. However, in pgadmin, I am still getting the same error...